# Cloud Vision API service is slow suddenly

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I'm using the Google Cloud Vision API.

Since June 2, Cloud Vision API services have slowed down.
Until June 1, I received a response within one second. 
However, from June 2, we need more than 2.5 seconds response time.

Our service quality is degraded, and my service users are complaining

Does this phenomenon only appear to me? What should I do?

[This is a graph representing the problem.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pz4hX.png)